# holomorphic function such that f(z) = Re(z) when |z|=1?

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is to compute integral
$\int_{|z|=1} Re(z)e^{z^2}$. Hint is to find a holomorphic function f such that f(z)=Re(z) when |z|=1.

I've been scratching my head and I can't think of such holomorphic function

Comment: why do you think such a function exists?

Comment: the exercise asks to compute an integral where the equation involves Re(z). the hint is to replace Re(z) with such holomorphic function

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I see; $(z+1/z)/2$ works of course in the punctured plane though it has a singularity at $0$ (one can easily show that any such functions - holomorphic that send the unit disc to a real set must have singularities inside the unit disc)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need! I'll keep this in mind. It's very handy

Comment: happy to be of help - I was a bit confused because as noted we need singularities inside the unit circle for this to work, but when you mentioned the integral context everything was clear, so it's really useful to mention the context of the problem

Comment: yes and the reason I didn't think of 1/z is also because I was thinking about a holomorphic everywhere function

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly holomorphic, but:

$f(\exp(i\theta))=\cos\theta$

[$=(\exp(i\theta)+\exp(-i\theta))/2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Then $\exp(i\theta)=z$ implies $\exp(-i\theta)=1/z$, so $f(z)=...$